# Need help in share point 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Anyone from share point 2010 developer? I am new to share point. I have requirement that I want to put few custom tab in share point list link. For example if I click Registration (custom list) link that page will open there I want to place some custom tab like Employee Department…etc

By default when page will open Employee tab will be highlighted and employee registration page will be opened and department registration page will be hidden. And When Department tab is clicked department registration page will be opened and employee registration page will be hidden.

How can I achieve this functionality and how to give the link from tab to corresponding registration page?

Your help is always heartily appreciated.

Thanks,

sumit

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might want a custom web part.  Take a look at these links to get started:

- http://blog.concurrency.com/sharepoint/create-a-custom-web-part-for-sharepoint-2010/
- http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/02/15/intro-to-sharepoint-2010-development-how-to-build-and-deploy-a-web-part.aspx

Things are much easier in 2010 than in 2007 especially for someone getting started with SharePoint.